# Use of Application.Current.Dispatcher for events outside dispatcher thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Question: Should "Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke" be put in the worker thread raising an event or in the UI code handling the event? It works fine either way but what is the better practice or difference?

In a WPF application that creates a news ticker, I am retrieving the body text from new Inbox emails via `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` and the `ItemAdd` event, which then raises an event that passes the body text. The main view model subscribes to this event as follows. In `OutlookReader` class:

```
private void OnEmailFoundWithSubjectMatchingFilter(_MailItem item)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        FoundEmailWithSubjectMatchingFilter?.Invoke(this, item.Body);
    });
}
```

And, in the `MainViewModel` class:

```
private void HandleEmailFeed(object sender, string e)
{
    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    //{
    var parser = new MailBodyParser();

    AddFeedItem(parser.Parse(e));
    //});
}
```

Comment: There isn't one right answer. Do whatever would be more consistent with what the users of the library would expect. Sometimes this is referred to as the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: I am inclined to think that the UI side should invoke the dispatcher, since the worker thread shouldn't really be responsible for how it results are used. Was really wondering if there is any technical/performance difference.

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking. The "UI thread" is, by convention, the dispatcher thread. If you are already executing code in the UI thread, there would be no need to call `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. You would _only_ ever call `Dispatcher.Invoke()` from threads _other than_ the UI thread.

Comment: Writing threaded code is never easy, it has a strong knack for failing when you are not looking.  With failure modes that are almost impossible to diagnose.  That makes not having any idea on what thread your code runs a giant code smell.  If you don't know then you can never *prove* that your code is thread-safe.  Never do that.

Comment: If you're afraid of the performance penalty of using the dispatcher when not needed, you can use the `CheckAccess` method: `if (!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) { // You should use invoke } else { // Invoke isn't required }`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ Peter Duniho: Thank you clarification on terminology. I have revised question to make more  clear. I am new to C# and trying to understand where the Dispatcher call should be used:  in the code raising the event (in this case thread running Outlook) or in the MainViewModel code (dispatcher thread) or if it makes no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should "Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke" be put in the worker thread raising an event or in the UI code handling the event?

The latter I would say. Mainly because the worker thread may be started in a class library that has no knowledge about any `System.Windows.Application` object.

So the worker thread should simply raise the event and then the client application is responsible for only updating the UI elements on the dispatcher thread on which they were originally created on. A class library shouldn't have to care about or even know about any dispatcher.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down, but, yes, this will be the answer. This is my fist SO question, and as  Peter Duniho mentioned, I could have worded it better. It wasn't until after I posted that I realized the question I really wanted answered was this: What pattern/practice is best for handling events between worker threads and the dispatcher thread in WPF? That, too, is probably too open ended, but I will refine it and post a new question. Thanks for your reply.